# AutoHotKey Debugger: Can't find SciTE COM object

Tags: debugging, scite

I just installed AutoHotKey_L and wrote my first script -actually copied an example. Saved the script and tried the debugger.

Found this

; Get the COM SciTE object
oSciTE := GetSciTEInstance()
if !oSciTE
{
    MsgBox, 16, SciTE4AutoHotkey Debugger, Can't find SciTE COM object!
    ExitApp
}

in the SciTEDebug.ahk file.

Now I know what's producing the error message, but I don't know why.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem.  I'm not much of a programmer so be don't be overly technical.

AutoHotKey_L, 32-bit
Windows 7

Dave